# Cannot install a module in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBOlC.png)

I'm trying to install a module in jupyter notebook, but it keeps on showing me this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
```

or even better -use requests instead:

```
pip install requests
```